# Write Json Object to lombok Object

Tags: json, lombok

I have a problem about write Json Object into lombok object.
Here ist mein Json Object:

````
```{"id": "1","name":"home","order": "1","isSubMenu": false,"path":"home","subMenu": null},{"id": "2","name":"user","order": "2","isSubMenu": false,"path":"usermanagement" ,"subMenu": [{"id": "21","name":"access","order": "1","isSubMenu": true,"path":"access" ,"subMenu": null},{"id": "22","name":"user","order": "2","isSubMenu": true,"path":"group" ,"subMenu": null},{"id": "23","name":"group","order": "3","isSubMenu": true,"path":"user" ,"subMenu": null}]}}```
````

and my lombok:

````
@Value
@JsonDeserialize()
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Menu {
    private  String id;
    private  String name;
    private  Integer order;
    private  Boolean isSubMenu;
    private  String path;
    private List<Menu> subMenuList;
}```

and my service:
```ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Menu menu = mapper.convertValue(outPutObject, Menu.class);
````

and Finally my Exception :

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of com.barman.framework.model.Menu (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('')at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]`

Answer (score 0):

As you've annotated your class with lomboks `@Value` it means you're defining your class to be immutable which means that the constructors have to initialise all members (as lombok will decorate them as being `final`). Jackson default deserializer works by calling an empty constructor, then calling setters on each of the members that match the fields in the JSON. If there is no default constructor (which you wont have with lomboks `@value`) then it throws the error you're seeing.

You basically have 2 options:

**1. Quick and dirty:**

Replace

```
@Value
```

with

```
@Data
@NoArgConstructor
```

BUT this will break the design of your class as it will no longer be immutable (as `@Data` adds setters). You will need to evaluate if this is acceptable for your design.

**2. Create a custom deserializer:**

In your menu class, update your `@JsonDeserialize` to:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MenuDeserializer.class)
```

and then define your Deserializer thus:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JacksonException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class MenuDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Menu> {

    @Override
    public Menu deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(new TypeReference<List<Menu>>() {        });
        return new Menu(
                node.get("id").asText(),
                node.get("name").asText(),
                node.get("order").asInt(),
                node.get("isSubMenu").asBoolean(),
                node.get("path").asText(),
                reader.readValue(node.get("subMenuList"))
        );
    }
}
```

This option is more code and a faff, but you maintain immutability which is what all the cool kids do